# why my inputs are not aligned?

Tags: css, input, textarea

I need some help.
I'm new with css, so I don't know why my input "textarea" is not vertical align with others inputs?
It's more 1 or 2px to right...

Here is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uxpedro/tDxc5/14/

```
form{
 width:255px;
 height:266px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top:200px;
}


input[type=text]{
  font-family:verdana;
  width:250px;
  height:40px;
  padding-left:5px; 
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
  border-style:none;
}

textarea{
  font-family:verdana;
  margin-top:30px;
  max-width:250px;
  min-width:250px;
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:200px;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
 }

input[type=submit]{
  margin-top:-3px;
  width:250px;
  height:40px;
  color:white;
  background-color:rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
  border-style:none;
  }
```

Comment: You have a `margin-top: 30px;` set for `textarea`. Change it to `margin-top:4px;`

Comment: Sorry, I was not very specific, I mean the vertical alignment, the "textarea" is more 1 or 2px to right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was the border on your textarea, it was not the submit button that wasn't wide enough, it was the extra width on the textarea.

Remember the box-model when styling your site.

Here's a updated fiddle, I am sorry if I messed too much with it I just wanted to make it simpler for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tDxc5/16/

Try setting the background of the form to red, that way you can see everything now is the width of the form (which I think was what you were trying to do.)

**A couple of things:**

I removed everything but the form so you could easily read it.

One rule to note is the `box-sizing: border-box;` - It generally calculates the padding you set on elements for you, so if you have something that's 200px in width and set padding 10px it will become 220px because you set padding on all sides to 10px. With that rule it will know to take 20px off the inital width to make it fit what you actually set it to.

I closed your inputs with /> because jsfiddle told me to, you don't have to do it.

Use `placeholder=""` instead of `value=""` - How to style placeholders: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

You should really not use height in these situations, for the textarea purpose as you did, I added a `resize: vertical;` to make sure it couldn't go out of the form element.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Chrome's user-agent stylesheet (a.k.a. the "default CSS style" of your browser) specifies, for textarea, a margin of 2px. Since you only declare the `margin-top` property, the three remaining margins are still set at 2px, as you can see from the inspector (accessible by right-clicking on the text area and select `Inspect element`).

To have it aligned with the rest just replace `margin-top:30px` with `margin:30px 0 0` and you're all set.